# Creating a global database connection on an mdi form

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview, ini

In my vb project, I have an mdi parent form to open other forms. On one form I have a DataGridView displaying a table that I made in SQL Server. The data loads fine if I set up the connection locally (on the form load with the DGV), but I have to make the connection global to keep it simpler and stop it constantly opening/closing the same connection.. I added the code to the mdi form, as below.

```
Public Class mdi1

Dim con As inifile = New inifile()
Dim constr = con.readconnectionstring()
```

I've already added the `Imports System.Data.OleDb` code, so why do I get the following error when compiling the code?

```
constr is not declared, it may be inaccessible due to its protection level
```

This error is in my form1_load subroutine (where the connection was originally being set to load the data to the DGV)

Comment: You are using OleDB to access SQL Server (tag)?

Comment: @Plutonix yes I am, I did try to use SqlClient but my teacher said to use OleDb, but both worked anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you appear to be a beginner I will try to tell you how to get this working, rather than best practise.

ensure your constr is accessible from anywhere by defining it in your MDI form as `Public`:

```
Public constr = con.readconnectionstring()
```

Now you can access this anywhere by using the fully qualified variable name:

```
mdi1.constr
```

Best practise would be probably to store this in its own "DataAccess" class rather than the MDI form

Comment: Hi, this has all worked and gotten rid of the error that I initially had, however, now in my SQL statement that is used to display the data I get a new error, which I will post in the original question.

Comment: No - please start a new question if you have a new error